# How to communicate between ViewModels? ( Prism event aggregator?)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, publish-subscribe

I'm new to C# and WPF, I'm making a small application and I figured It'd be a good opportunity to learn and use the MVVM pattern.

It's definitely made things a little more difficult than I had intended for a small app, but It's a good learning experience. I've been able to follow things up until now. I seem to be completely lost on how to properly implement a way of having the ViewModels interact with each other.

I have the MainWindowView and an OverlayView, I want to be able to draw a rectangle on the overlay view from the the main ViewModel. I want a way to be able to just broadcast an event from the MainViewModel and have the OverlayView hear it and draw the rectangle as specified. I'd also think it'd be handy to add a 'CloseAllWindows' broadcast once I get it working.

From my research, the easiest way to do this is with a framework like Prism. I've been trying to set up an Event Aggregator from the Prism framework but I can't get it working no matter what I try. I've looked all over for articles or tutorials but they all seem to be outdated, have broken links or I just can't seem to understand them and get them to work.

Here is what I've got so far:

**Events.cs** :

```
using System.Windows;
using Prism.Events;

namespace Application.Overlay {
    public class DrawRectEvent : PubSubEvent<Rect> {
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
 namespace Application.ViewModels {

    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase {

        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        public MainWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            WindowLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(WindowLoaded);
            TestDrawCommand = new RelayCommand(TestDraw);
        }

        public RelayCommand TestDrawCommand { get; set; }
        public void TestDraw() {
            Console.WriteLine("Publishing DrawRect Broadcast");
            Size size = new Size(100, 100);
            Point point = new Point(50, 50);
            Rect rect = new Rect(point, size);

            eventAggregator.GetEvent<DrawRectEvent>().Publish(rect);
        }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Application {

    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        TextBoxOutputter outputter;

        public MainWindow() {
            this.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel(eventAggregator);
            InitializeComponent();

        // Route console output to ConsoleOutput TextBox
        outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(ConsoleOutput);
        Console.SetOut(outputter);
    }
```

**OverlayViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Application.Overlay : BindableBase {

    public class OverlayViewModel {
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public OverlayViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {

        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<DrawRectEvent>().Subscribe(DrawRectEventHandler);
        }

        private void DrawRectEventHandler(Rect rect) {
            Console.WriteLine("Signal Received, Drawing Rectangle!");
        }
```

**OverlayView.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Application.Overlay {

    public partial class Overlay : Window {

        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        public Overlay() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Top = 0;
            Left = 0;
            this.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            this.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;

            this.DataContext = new OverlayViewModel(eventAggregator);
        }
```

With this code it compiles fine but I get a "Null reference Exception" "Object reference not set to an in`stance of an Object" when running it, it's referring to line 9 in the OverlayViewModel:

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<DrawRectEvent>().Subscribe(DrawRectEventHandler);
```

I'm not sure if I'm passing the right thing in to the new ViewModel instance in the codebehind, I'm not sure what else you'd pass in though.

If you see what I'm doing wrong or you have an up to date guide that shows a more effective way than what I'm doing, then I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to go back to basics and learn more of the fundamentals of C# (like interfaces, generics and behaviors) so I can properly understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? I suppose your `eventAggregator` is null. I think it's more about prism not about _C# (like interfaces, generics and behaviors)_

Comment: It's about very basic C# basics like default values of fields... `private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;` begins with `null` and remains `null`, unless told otherwise. Let the view create its view model via `ViewModelLocator` and inject directly into the view model or go view model first, but you won't be able to inject into the view.

Comment: You've never actually created an instance of the `EventAggregator`, you're just passing around the interface. Check out this GitHub repo full of examples of how Prism pieces work. They put a lot of work into making this code readable https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/14-UsingEventAggregator

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just getting started, I won't bother going too deeply on explaining the fundamentals, I'll just jump straight to the part of 'how do we get your current code to build and work' and you can keep moving forward on learning.

As far as I can tell from the code you provided, it looks like you've never actually created an instance of the `EventAggregator` (unless you've set up an IoC container, which I don't see any tell-tale signs that you have done that yet).

So in your code::

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    TextBoxOutputter outputter;

    public MainWindow() {
        this.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel(eventAggregator);
        InitializeComponent();

    // Route console output to ConsoleOutput TextBox
    outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(ConsoleOutput);
    Console.SetOut(outputter);
}
```

You are creating an instance of the `ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel` and passing in your empty field `eventAggregator`. Right before this, you need to fill that field with an actual instance. So try this::

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    TextBoxOutputter outputter;

    public MainWindow() {
        this.eventAggregator = new EventAggregator(); //<---
        this.DataContext = new ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel(eventAggregator);
        InitializeComponent();

    // Route console output to ConsoleOutput TextBox
    outputter = new TextBoxOutputter(ConsoleOutput);
    Console.SetOut(outputter);
}
```